# PermissionError [Errno 13] when writing to a file after using lockfile in python

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, file-locking, filelock

I would like to safely open and write to a file, so I decided to use the fileLock python library. This is my code:

```
            with filelock.FileLock('../rsc/datasets/train/' + server_predict.remove_special_chars(str(id_park)) + '.csv'):
                with open('../rsc/datasets/train/' + server_predict.remove_special_chars(str(id_park)) + '.csv', mode='a') as file:
                    for line in data_by_id.values:
                        a = "\"" + server_predict.remove_special_chars(str(line[0])) + "\",\"" + str(line[1]) + "\"," + str(line[2]) #+ "\n"
                        file.write(a)
```

However, this raises a PermissionError exception, sometimes on the

> file.write(a)

line and others in the line

> for line in data_by_id.values

Any clue where this error might come from? Is it me that I do not understand how fileLock works??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate lock-file like shown [here:](https://pypi.org/project/filelock/)

> ```
> from filelock import Timeout, FileLock
>
> lock = FileLock("high_ground.txt.lock")
> with lock:
>     open("high_ground.txt", "a").write("You were the chosen one.")
> ```
>
> **Don't use** a *FileLock* to lock the file you want to write to, instead create a separate
> *.lock* file as shown above.

Note the `.lock` extension for the `FileLock`.

Comment: Oh, my understanding was that the library created the ".lock" file. Thanks!!